# How add Git from development with the Node-RED editor in Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

**Context:**

In Bluemix, I developed an application using the boilerplate Node-RED Starter. I developed using the Node-RED editor through Bluemix. All tests were done through this editor.

I have a very little knowledge of Node.js and Node-RED. I don't understand the architecture for Node-RED. It is hard to find a solution to my problem because I don't even know where the files are developed with the Node-RED editor. I only found with a local Node-Red quick try some files in .node-red in my local user. I could not find any information about the files that are developed/generated in the Node-RED site.

**Problem:**

In the Bluemix Node-RED app, I added Git. However, then Git does not see any file change from my development using the Bluemix Node-RED editor.

**Failed solutions:**

I tried to locally download the files to add them myself in Git. However, this solution didn't work because all the documentation I could find was to download the boilerplate, but the download link doesn't work. This solution didn't work: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/240124/how-to-download-the-files-from-the-bluemix-app-tha.html

I tried to set up a local Node-RED environment, but quoted there was many nodes to add already in Bluemix. Also, I couldn't understand what files to add in Git that wasn't part of the product (Node.js/Node-RED)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Node-RED runs on Bluemix the flows are stored in the Cloudant Database instance that is created by the Node-RED Boiletplate.

The way Bluemix works, there is no state information stored on the file system. This means the system can move running applications to an new instance and not have to worry about moving any changes in file system, it just redeplys the app to a new instance and supplies the connection information to attached services (in this case the Cloudant DB).

At the moment there is no way to version control flows from within Node-RED (it is being looked at for future releases), your best bet is to export the flow when ever you want to save a version and manually check this into a version control system such as git.

Comment: Thank you. I hope they'll add git to manage the source fo the flows, when you have one tab export is ok, multiple tabs and sub tabs is more tedious. :-)

Comment: @hardlib is this still the state of affairs?  I'm looking for how to do this.  I have to use Watson, because my client has a huge credit with them, but I'm getting concerned about not having outside storage of my configuration and assets from the console.

Comment: Git support for versioning flows is due in release 0.18 I think which is due soon